# OSID Linux 3160 not found error

Tags: software-installation

I've run a install script for specific software, after several steps I got this error in terminal;

```
System name:  Linux sorbilene-Veriton-M4610G 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

System release number translated to  3160

OSID Linux 3160 not found in Makefile.config - remove Makefile and STOP
```

and make file is terminated.

Is there anyone can explain what this error is related?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. open Makefile.config with any text editor (sudo permissions required);
2. find the line starting wiht “OS_ID Linux 0001 ”, it might be “OS_ID Linux 0001 3000”;
3. change 3000 to 3160.

Should work it out!